# Avoid styles in a sheet apply to only one element

Tags: css

I have a style sheet that consists styles that affects two elements in my page, I can't change the classes for my elements, is there any way to make sure that the styles apply to only one specific element in my page not for the other.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the first-of-type selector?

ex.

```
p:first-of-type {
  background:#ff0000;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can do that by specificity.

Select topmost parents and go on targeting their childs until you reach the last child element that you need to apply styles for.

If you can add an id to it or if any id is dynamically generated, just create a specificity for the same and you will get your thing done.

**For Instance,**

```
body div#your id name div.your_class1 > div.your_class_element_that_you_want_to_style{/* your values */}
```

Hope this helps.

***PS:** In the illustration, div is used as a reference and you can select the elements accordingly to your HTML structure.*

Answer (score 1):

If there are two, you use the `:first-of-type` selector:

```
div.selector:first-of-type {
    /* styles here */
}
```